# How to find result with multiple where condition

Tags: mysql

Below is my product entity table,

I want to fetch data from table where user_id should not be equal to 12, 36,43

How Can I write a select query for that,

Current sql query -

select * from catalog_product_entity where entity_id = 12345;

I want result without having user_id 12, 36, 43

desc catalog_product_entity;

```
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                 | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| entity_id        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| entity_type_id   | smallint(8) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| attribute_set_id | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| type_id          | varchar(32)          | NO   |     | simple              |                |
| sku              | varchar(64)          | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| created_at       | datetime             | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at       | datetime             | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| has_options      | smallint(1)          | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| required_options | tinyint(1) unsigned  | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| user_id          | mediumint(11)        | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

select distinct user_id from catalog_product_entity;

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       8 |
|       4 |
|       9 |
|       1 |
|      12 |
|      10 |
|      13 |
|      15 |
|       7 |
|      33 |
|      34 |
|      35 |
|      36 |
|      43 |
|      38 |
|      49 |
|      39 |
+---------+
```

Comment: Hint, use `not in`...

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Query:**

```
select * from catalog_product_entity 
   where user_id not in (12,36,43) 
   and entity_id = 12345;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE ... NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity
WHERE entity_id = 12345 AND
      user_id NOT IN (12, 36, 43)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from catalog_product_entity where user_id not in (12,36,43) and entity_id = 12345 order by desc
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

With not in:

`select * 
  from catalog_product_entity 
 where entity_id = 12345
   and user_id not in (12, 36, 43);`

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp